# Multi Line Comments and/or Display

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display multiline comments or messages within the browser? For example, if I wanted a user to click a box and have the browser display multiple lines in the format of question #1-10:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Mathematics Review</h1>

        <p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>

        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

        <p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>

        <script>
            function myFunction() { 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Question #1";
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Ultimately, when the user clicks the "Click Me" button, questions should display like this:

```
Question #1
Question #2
Question #3
Question #4
and so on....
```

Also, do different browsers behave differently when trying to implement this?

Comment: Correction:
Question #1
Next line:  Question #2
Next line:  Question #3
Next line:  Question #4
And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare global a variable, clickcount then increment it whenever running myFunction.

On more thing you should remind is keeping comment between script tag avoiding some parsing errors among browsers like firefox, chrome, IE etc.

Here is my solution for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>Mathematics Review</h1>

  <p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>

  <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  var clickcount = 1;
  function myFunction() { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Question #" + clickcount++;
  }
  -->
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

And, You can use a [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function, if you want some effect like auto increment the number at some period of time.

Here is another one with 10 iteration every time you just click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Mathematics Review</h1>

<p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>

<button type="button" onclick="try10Iter()">Click Me!(10 iteration)</button>
<button onclick="myVar = setTimeout(try10Iter, 500)">Try it</button>
<button onclick="clearTimeout(myVar)">Stop it</button>

<p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>

<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
        var clickcount = 1;
        var countVar;

        function stopIterAt(condition)
        {
            if(clickcount == condition) 
            {
                clearInterval(countVar);
                clickcount = 0;
            }
        }

        function myFunction() { 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Question #" + clickcount++;
            stopIterAt(11)
        }

        function try10Iter()
        {
            countVar = window.setInterval(myFunction, 500);
        }
    -->
</script>

</body>
```

I borrowed some code from the [site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Regards,

Comment: @tommybee

Thanks for solution.  Ideally, I am trying to have the user click the "click me" button and the Questions can flash from #1 to #10.  Any suggestions on this?  I'll keep playing with the code.  Thanks for the help bud.

Comment: @PreYvin, Thanks for choose my answer, I add another one for you, It is just my opinion. I think you can find more. good luck

Comment: @tommybee

Very cool setInterval function.  Creative if I may add.  I suppose depending on how comfortable the client/user is, they may opt for increments rather than individual mouse clicks.  Take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `<br>` tags to your `innerHTML` value:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Question #1<br>Question #2<br>Question #3<br>Question #4";
```

Comment: Think I found what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help bud.
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>Mathematics Review</h1>

  <p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>

  <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  var clickcount = 1;
  function myFunction() { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =    
  "What is 2+2?<br>What is 6 divided by 3?";
  "a test" + clickcount++;
  }
  -->
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 1;      
function myFunction() { 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>Question #"+(count++);
}
```

```html
<h1>Mathematics Review</h1>
<p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>
```

Comment: @PreYvin It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>Question #" + ++question;
```

where `question` is a *global* variable initialized to zero - see demo below:

```js
var question = 0;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>Question #" + ++question;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mathematics Review</h1>

<p>Click Below For a Quick Review:</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo">Please Take Notes!</p>
```